# DBASE file reading Limitation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, geospatial, shapefile, dbase

I have a Dbase file (*.dbf) which I am currently reading using Microsoft OLEDG Jet Provier.

Now the issue is that my Dbase file is more then 2GB in size and as per the limitation of Jet Provider(Which only runs on 32 bit) I can only read 2 GB worth of data. Is there any alternative method to read the Dbase file? other then Jet OLEDB provider. I tried all the Microsoft OLEDB providers but all seem to read only 2 GB data.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase iAnywhere  (Advantage-Database-Server), and it works / recognizes DBF files directly...

Comment: Can I used Sybase iAnywhere with Microsoft?